# Filtering/Matching eventlog records

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, event-log

Goal: Create a script that grabs event logs for last day from specific computers and then look in the message section to filter data based on specific IPs (First) then filter that data again only for items that start with specific keyword, then output to HTML.

Code:

```
$fileDate = (Get-Date -Format ddMMyyyy) + ".html"
$EventGrab = Invoke-Command {
    Get-EventLog -LogName Security -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) -EntryType FailureAudit
} -ComputerName whatever
$EventGrab |
    Sort-Object -Property TimeWritten -Descending |
    Select-String -InputObject {$_.TimeWritten,$_.message} -Pattern "10.1.2.13" |
    ConvertTo-Html |
    Out-File C:\$fileDate
```

Rough Steps:

1. Creates file with Date.
2. Grab event logs from Security log with FailureAudit in the last 24 hours.
3. Check the message section for the above pattern (devices).
4. Converts to HTML and outputs to file with the date from step 1.

Problem is between step 3 and 4; I need to figure out to filter the message again after step 3 that would take the message field and only look in it for a specific syntax (Ex. LTC) and then output that data if it found it into the HTML file.

I'm thinking its just another `Select-String`, or something but can't figure it out.

Example input (@ `Select-String` section):

```
02/08/2017 15:51:57 Network Policy Server denied access to a user.
Contact the Network Policy Server administrator for more information.
User:
Security ID:                    S-1-0-0
Account Name:                   <scrubbed>
Account Domain:                 <scrubbed>
Fully Qualified Account Name:   <scrubbed>

Client Machine:
Security ID:                    S-1-0-0
Account Name:                   -
Fully Qualified Account Name:   -
OS-Version:                     -
Called Station Identifier:      00-1B-53-41-5A-57
Calling Station Identifier:     F8-CA-B8-57-1A-9B

NAS:
NAS IPv4 Address:               10.1.2.13
NAS IPv6 Address:               -
NAS Identifier:                 -
NAS Port-Type:                  Ethernet
NAS Port:                       50324

RADIUS Client:
Client Friendly Name:           <scrubbed>
Client IP Address:              10.1.2.13

Authentication Details:
Connection Request Policy Name: <scrubbed>
Network Policy Name:            -
Authentication Provider:        Windows
Authentication Server:          <scrubbed>
Authentication Type:            PEAP
EAP Type:                       Microsoft: Secured password (EAP-MSCHAP v2)
Account Session Identifier:             -
Logging Results:                Accounting information was written to the local log file.
Reason Code:                    8
Reason:                         The specified user account does not exist.
```

Expected output:

The above changed so that only account name is `host/LTC<whatever>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Where-Object` for filtering the records and `Select-String` for extracting strings from the message:

```
$EventGrab |
    Sort-Object -Property TimeWritten -Descending |
    Where-Object {
        $_.Message -like '*10.1.2.13*' -and
        $_.Message -like '*LTC*'
    } |
    Select-Object TimeWritten, @{n='Account';e={
        Select-String -InputObject $_.Message -Pattern 'Account Name:\s+(.*LTC.*)' |
            Select-Object -Expand Matches |
            ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value }
    }} |
    ConvertTo-Html |
    Out-File C:\$fileDate
```

Comment: Hmm. That didn't seem to function properly (getting no data output). I think I may have explained it wrong, or I'm missing something. In the $_.Message data from the EventGrab it'll spew back a bunch of information in that Message field, I'm looking to match within that huge amount of data either 10.1.2.13 or LTC, which looks right above, but I'm wondering if its looking for only '10.1.2.13' and/or 'LTC'  being the string instead of just being part of the string within the huge message.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample input and output.

Comment: Added some Input/Output expected.

Comment: As `-match` is RegEx based I'd change the pattern to `'10\.1\.2\.13'` or put it into a var `$PatternIP = [RegEx]::Escape('10.1.2.13')`. Otherwise a date like 10/1/2013 could also match.

Comment: @LotPings Good point. Thanks for the heads up. Rather than escaping the patterns for `-match` I switched to wildcard matches, though. Should provide slightly better performance.